# Timeout fails to change flag used in while loop

Tags: ajax, synchronization

I'm trying to emulate a synchronous ajax call by blocking for a short period of time and then flipping a flag in the AJAX return. But the flags don't get updated, even though the time limit is reached. Instead the browser just hangs. I've tested in Firefox and Safari with the same results.

Broken design:

```
function syncAjax(args, timeLimit) {

    var obj = {}, 
        outOfTime = false,
        timeout, k, 
        response = {returned: false, failed: false, responseText: null};

    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        outOfTime = true;
    }, timeLimit);
    for(k in args) {
        if(args.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            obj[k] = args[k];
        }
    }
    obj.success = function(responseText) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        response.returned = true;
        response.responseText = responseText;
    };
    obj.failure = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        response.returned = true;
        response.failed = true;
    };
    // obj["async"] = true; // (automatically async)
    $.ajax(obj);
    // insert spinner timeout
    while(true) {
        if(response.returned || outOfTime) break; 
    }
    return response;

}
```

Sample usage:

```
function doIt() {

    var response = syncAjax({
        url: "webpage.php", 
        data: {x: 5}, 
    }, 500);
    if(!response.returned) {
        // do time out stuff
    } else if(response.failed) {
        // do failed stuff
    } else {
        console.log(response.responseText);
        // do success stuff with response.responseText
    }

}

// !! executing this function will lock up your browser !!
// doIt();
```

Comment: do you think javascript uses multiple threads?

Comment: @Garr I thought timeouts were executed in separate threads from the main thread.

Comment: Not in any major browser. javascript doesn't have any threadsafe utility, like semaphores, so if it were multithreaded there would be a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript cannot call your timeout until you return from your function. setTimeout is not a threaded call.

You could do this for your loop:

```
var start = Date().getTime();
while( start+timeLimit > Date().getTime() ) ;
```